# iOS - NavBar logo title is shifting to the left

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uinavigationbar

NavBar logo title is shifting to the left because of rightBarButtonItem. How can I set its X position center horizontally.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
    if let navBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar {

        let image = UIImageView()
        image.image = UIImage(named: "Icon.png")
        image.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)
        image.center = CGPoint(x: navBar.center.x, y: navBar.center.y-19)
        navBar.addSubview(image)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you used Storyboard:

If you view your warnings, Xcode should notify you that the Frame will be different at run time. Often, it can correct that for you automatically if you click on the yellow triangle and select "Update constraints automatically".

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Hi there @penatheboss. Given that they used storyboard (and it appears they have), the solution is included.

Comment: There is no notify for that. I added the message button programmatically. I think, because of that.